# Understanding Entitlements and Offering Configurations

Tags: swift, in-app-purchase, revenuecat

What would be the right configuration in RevenueCat in the following two scenarios...

1. What would be the right configuration if I have a non-consumable in-app purchase and an Auto Renewable Subscription? Do I need two separate Entitlements with an Offering on each one?
2. What would be the right configuration if I have a non-consumable in-app purchase and two Auto Renewable Subscriptions (a monthly and yearly)? Do I need two Entitlements, one for the Auto Renewable Subscriptions which would contain two Offerings and one for the non-consumables which would contain one offering?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Entitlements should be thought of as access levels (e.g. "Pro", "Pro Plus"), and Offerings are different ways to purchase that access level (e.g. "Monthly", "Annual", "Lifetime"). For your specific questions:

1. If the non-consumable and subscription IAP unlock the same content
   in your app then you would have one Entitlement (e.g. "pro") with
   two Offerings (e.g. "lifetime" and "monthly").
2. Similar to #1, if all the products unlock the same content then you
   would have one Entitlement (e.g. "pro") with three Offerings (e.g.
   "lifetime", "monthly" and "annual").

Comment: @ enc_life - So in a sense, Entitlements mimic the behavior of groups in `itunesconnect` where it can contain multiple in-app purchase options but only one can be purchased from within the group, correct?

Comment: @fs_tigre Yes, entitlements are very similar to subscription groups in ITC, however RevenueCat doesn't enforce only one product being owned at a time (that can be setup with a Subscription Group in ITC though)